# Sencha Ext JS DragDropManager not allowing me to drag an element above the window

Tags: extjs

I need to be able to drag an element ABOVE the confines of my browser window, my grid has thousands of items in it and the drag and drop capabilities of my Sencha Ext JS 6.6.0 version seems to be limited to only allowing me to drag an item to the top of my browser window instead of allowing me to scroll automatically while at the same time Mousedown'ing on the element and weee... scrolling to the top.. (of the grid not the window)...

wee... why does this have to be so difficult it needs to take up days and days of a developers time?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing containerScroll attribute on my plugin.